# ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type - Python

Tags: python, sql

Estoy aprendiendo sobre Python y SQLite y tengo un problema a la hora de checkear si el id del producto es el mismo que el de algun valor dentro de la base de datos.

```
import sqlite3

conexion = sqlite3.connect("codigos.db")

consulta = conexion.cursor()

a = int(input("escanear codigo de barras: "))

consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?", a)
print(consulta.fetchone())

consulta.close()
conexion.commit()
conexion.close()
```

A la hora de ejecutarse hasta la linea

```
a = int(input("escanear codigo de barras: "))
```

anda todo bien pero desp me salta este error:

```
File "buscar.py", line 9, in <module>
    consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?", a)
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.execute` espera un iterable como segundo argumento, sin importar que solo sea un parámetro. Por ejemplo, cualquiera de éstas formas es válida:

**`Tupla`**

```
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = ?", (a, ))
```

Observase que es:

```
(a, )
  ^
  ^
```

Si se pasas `(a)` es lo mismo que ahora haces y es un error muy común:

- `(a)` es igual que `a`, son solo dos paréntesis indicando orden de evaluación.
- `(a, )` literal de tupla.
- `(a, b)` literal de tupla

**`Lista`**

```
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = ?", [a])
```

**`Diccionario`**

```
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = :id", {"id": a}) # named style
```

Un ejemplo completo reproducible para probar:

```
import sqlite3


conexion = sqlite3.connect("") # DB temporal en memoria

consulta = conexion.cursor()

consulta.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE producto(
        id INTEGUER,
        nombre TEXT
        )
        """)
values = ((1, "Producto A"), (2, "Producto B"))
consulta.executemany("INSERT INTO producto(id, nombre) VALUES(?, ?)", values)

a = int(input("escanear codigo de barras: "))

consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = ?", (a, ))
print(consulta.fetchone())
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = :id", {"id": a})
print(consulta.fetchone())
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE id = ?", [a])
print(consulta.fetchone())
```

Comment: Hola! Muchismas gracias por la explicacion! muy clara y detallada. Se agradece.
Ahora tengo el siguiente problema: 
File "buscar.py", line 9
    consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?", [a])
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

y lo unico que hice fue cambiar a esto: 
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?", [a])